# Question regarding a imaginary number problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is divided into 3 parts, part a), b) and c). I understood a) and b) just fine, but it the last question im struggling with.

Here we go:
Let $Q=\cos(2\pi/5)+i\sin(2\pi/5)$

a) show $Q$ is a root of $z^5 - 1 = 0$

b) Show that $(Q^4 + Q^3 + Q^2 + Q + 1)(Q-1) = Q^5 -1$ 
Then deduce that
$Q^4 + Q^3 + Q^2 + Q + 1 = 0$

c) Hence show that $\cos\frac{2\pi}{5} + \cos\frac{4\pi}{5} = -\frac{1}{2}$

So here i write out $Q^4 + Q^3 + Q^2 + Q + 1$ using 
$Q = \cos\frac{2\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}$

which is correct according to the solution, however, the next step throws me off so badly.

This:

$$1 + \cos \frac{2\pi}{5} + i\sin \frac{2\pi}{5} + \cos\frac{4\pi}{5} + i\sin\frac{4\pi}{5} + \cos \frac{6\pi}{5} + i\sin \frac{6\pi}{5} + \cos \frac{8\pi}{5} + i\sin \frac{8\pi}{5}$$

Turns into this:

$$1 + \cos\frac{2\pi}{5} + i\sin \frac{2\pi}{5} + \cos \frac{4\pi}{5} + i\sin \frac{4\pi}{5} + \cos \frac{4\pi}{5} - i\sin \frac{4\pi}{5} + \cos \frac{2\pi}{5} - i\sin \frac{2\pi}{5}$$

So could someone be so kind to explain to me what exactly is going on between these two steps? Because im totally clueless :/ Everything up to this point, and what comes after is all fine and dandy, but its the last two stars that i dont get. Why do the sings change when the angles are replaced? Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get from $cos(6\pi/5)$ to $cos(4\pi/5)$ you just have to remember, that $\pi$ is symmetric around any multiple of $\pi$:

$cos(\pi + x) = cos(\pi - x)$

you have

$cos(\pi + \frac{\pi}{5})$ and $cos(\pi + \frac{2\pi}{5})$ 
which is therefore the same as:
$cos(\pi - \frac{\pi}{5})$ and $cos(\pi - \frac{2\pi}{5})$

sinus is antisymmetric around multiples of $\pi$ (that's the reasons the signs from those terms change):

$sin(\pi + x) = - sin(\pi - x)$

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos\frac{6\pi}{5}=\cos(2\pi-\frac{4\pi}{5})=\cos\frac{4\pi}{5}$$ and 
$$\cos\frac{8\pi}{5}=\cos(2\pi-\frac{2\pi}{5})=\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}$$
From your last equation (real part):
$$2\cos\frac{2 \pi}{5} +2 \cos\frac{4 \pi}{5} +1=0 $$ since $z^n-1=0$. 
Hence$$\cos\frac{2 \pi}{5} + \cos\frac{4 \pi}{5} =-\frac{1}{2}$$